# I have server, what recommendet to do with it?

Tags: linux

my server: 1GB ram, AMD ATHLON 2000mhz, 60GB HDD, Debian 6 OS. I have emty server and thinking what to do with it. Game server dont want. Maiby some one more server resurses ? Shell or etc ?

Comment: Perhaps you should read http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: Sell it on ebay/craigslist.

Comment: Give me a user account.

Answer (score 1):

Well.... if you don't know what to do with it, probably you don't need it! So you can maybe use it as a desktop or unplug it and save energy! ;)